# Any good ideas to implement a neat UI for a nested tree in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using awesome_nested_set. And there are of course many JS libraries. Anything particularly good to use for trees, with Drag-and-drop and ease of use ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In one project, I had to implement a full tree using Awesome_nested_set with drag-and-drop, editing, creation of children, etc.

I used jsTree (http://www.jstree.com/) and it was rather easy (only about 50 lines of custom JS).